# Setting up complex network in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Prior to physically setting up a number of servers to run Linux, I would like to set it up in VirtualBox or similar software first. All of the instructions on setting this up don't explain how to do more than four vms (one for each network adapter). I need to use more than four vms.

My intention is to set up router using Alpine or Untangle for the os. The first network adapter would be for connecting to the internet, and the other three would then be used for only three other servers, which is not going to be enough. Ideally, what I would like is a virtual switch or hub or router.

I am willing to use a different vm software if that would make it easier/possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Where's the complexity?

Comment: I need to setup more than four servers; the maximum VirtualBox seems to support is four.

Comment: Are you planning to add more network adapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtualbox actually supports [eight virtual network interfaces per guest](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html). The first four can be configured through the GUI. To configure all of them, you would have to use the [command-line `VboxManage` utility `modifyvm` option](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm). The specific commands are listed in section 8.8.2 of the manual, for example:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm vm-name --nic5 hostonly
VBoxManage modifyvm vm-name --hostonlyadapter5 "vboxnet0"
```

Regarding the number of other guests, you're not limited to pairs of guests. To set up connections from one guest to another, You define either a [host-only network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly) or an [internal network](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal). These act as LANs.

When setting up a virtual network interface on a guest, you can associate that interface with a particular virtual network. Any reasonable number of guests can attach to the same virtual network an communicate with each other, just as if they were physical hosts plugged into the same switch or hub.

So your virtual router guest could attach to seven different LANs, and each virtual LAN could have any reasonable number of other guests attached to it.